# Automatic font selection for Chinese character sets

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, itext

I see iText supports automatic font selection based on individual glyphs. This works by searching font libs included in the `FontSelector` for the particular glyph and selects a character from a different font lib if it does not exist in font libs defined higher up the list.

I have been able to configure font extentions in Jasper to support asian and latin character sets by choosing a large unicode font library such as "Arial Unicode MS" which has a super comprehensive character set. However good looking libraries like that are subject to pricey licensing!! Not surprisingly considering the amount of work involved... Any single free font libraries supporting both chinese and latin are generally created to cater for effective chinese character rendering and the latin characters' beauty suffer as a result ;)

So final a question: is there a mechanism for utilising iText's automatic font selection feature in jasper?

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand; you want to use the users own fonts in stead of supplying "Arial Unicode MS" with your application.

```
public class FontList extends ArrayList<String>
{
    public FontList()
    {
        for (final String fontName : GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames())
        {
            final Font f = new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 10);
            //first character in CJK area
            if (f.canDisplay('\u4E00'))
            {
                add(fontName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A new FontList will give you a list with all available fonts for chinese, japanese and korean.

You will need more logic to 'automatically' select the 'best' font; you could look for "Arial" in its name, to give it a higher priority. "Ume" and "WenQuanYi" and finally for "Dialog"

Maybe best to let the user choose which one to use. If no fonts are available, give advice on how to install the fonts [e.g.](http://www.clearchinese.com/resources/fonts.htm).

Comment: The question is about a solution in Jasper not iText unfort. I am guessing that is why someone gave you a -1 :(